# In ADS, what are the differences between the lumped components and the lumped component models?

Tags: ads

I'm trying to put in some ideal inductors and capacitors into my schematic, but there are two options: "Inductor" and "Inductor Model".

What are the differences between the two?

Comment: Try  putting one of each in your schematic and see.

Comment: @ThePhoton I will take a look at that, but if the end result looks the same?

Comment: Have you tried actually reading the documentation? For example, by googling "ADS inductor model site:keysight.com" I got [this](http://edadocs.software.keysight.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=10914491).

Comment: @ThePhoton yes I've read that. All I noticed are different parameters between the two, however. Did I miss something?

Comment: The fact that a model doesn't have any pins?

Comment: Did you read in the documentation for the L element where it has a model parameter that lets you refer to a model? And the description of what happens when you specify a model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A model is not a circuit element. It doesn't have any terminals that can connect it to wires. It just collects some parameters so that actual circuit elements can be made alike by referring to the model.

It's not common to use models for passive elements, but it's very common to use them for active devices like BJTs, MOSFETs, or diodes.